# Identify Common Lawn Varieties

Tags: identification, lawn, grass

I've run into this problem and I'm sure others will too:

**I want to know what variety of lawn I've got.**

Knowing your lawn type is important for: watering, PH levels, fertiliser, etc. And if you didn't plant it (like me), how do you know what you've got?

To be generic enough for general consumption:

1. Cover common lawn varieties - Couch, Bermuda, Buffalo, Kikuyu, Fescue, etc.
2. Have image
3. Have short description on how to **identify** (rather than care for) the the lawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a site called [thelawnguide.com.au](http://thelawnguide.com.au) which describes and shows small pictures of commonly used lawn grasses in Australia, not sure how much use it'll be, but can't find anything else.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what country you're in.
I had a book called "Be your own lawn expert" by David Gerald Hessayon. It shows the UK varieties (Bent, fescue, meadow grass, Rye) and you can identify them by the shape of the leaf base